# handsontable.js, the meged cell is not meged when use the downloadFile plugin

Tags: excel, handsontable

i want to export the table i generated
the table cell is merged
but when i export the file by useing the downloadFile plugin
the file can be downloaded successfully but the cell is not merged,it become the raw data
why?

this is my code

```
const container = document.getElementById('table-container');
  let table = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: [
      ['序号 ', '脱模角度 ', ' 纹理深度（μm） ', ' 纹理深度（μm） ', ' 纹理深度（μm） ', ' 纹理深度（μm） '], 
      ['序号 ', '脱模角度 ', '皮革纹 ', '几何纹 ', '梨地纹 ', '其他常用纹理 '], 
      ['1 ', '1° ', '13 ', '10 ', '15 ', '13 '], 
      ['2 ', '2° ', '26 ', '20 ', '20 ', '26 '], 
      ['3 ', '3° ', '39 ', '30 ', '30 ', '39 '], 
      ['4 ', '4° ', '52 ', '40 ', '40 ', '52 '], 
      ['5 ', '5° ', '65 ', '50 ', '50 ', '65 '], 
      ['6 ', '6° ', '78 ', '60 ', '60 ', '78 '], 
      ['7 ', '7° ', '91 ', '70 ', '70 ', '91 '], 
      ['8 ', '8° ', '104 ', '80 ', '80 ', '104 '], 
      ['9 ', '9° ', '117 ', '90 ', '90 ', '117 '], 
      ['10 ', '10° ', '130 ', '100 ', '100 ', '130 '], 
      ['11 ', '11° ', '143 ', '110 ', '—— ', '143 '], 
      ['12 ', '12° ', '156 ', '120 ', '—— ', '156 '], 
      ['13 ', '13° ', '—— ', '130 ', '—— ', '—— '], 
      ['14 ', '14° ', '—— ', '140 ', '—— ', '—— '], 
      ['15 ', '15° ', '—— ', '150 ', '—— ', '—— '], 
    ],
    mergeCells: [
      {'row': 0, 'col': 0, 'rowspan': 2, 'colspan': 1}, 
      {'row': 0, 'col': 1, 'rowspan': 2, 'colspan': 1}, 
      {'row': 0, 'col': 2, 'rowspan': 1, 'colspan': 4}
    ],
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    height: 450,
    className: 'htCenter htMiddle',
    stretchH: 'all',
    licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation', // for non-commercial use only
  });
})

 const exportPlugin = table.getPlugin('exportFile');
  // export to downloadable file (named: MyFile.csv)
  exportPlugin.downloadFile('csv', {
    bom: true,
    columnDelimiter: ',',
    columnHeaders: false,
    rowHeaders:false,
    exportHiddenColumns: true,
    exportHiddenRows: true,
    fileExtension: 'csv',
    filename: 'Excel-[YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]',
    mimeType: 'text/csv',
    rowDelimiter: '\r\n',
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Handsontable's `ExportToFile` plugin export only RAW data in the format of a CSV file. This means that formatting, comments, and styling is not attached. Merging is a form of cell formatting. If you'd like to have merged cells I would rather look for HTML > XLSX converted among the MIT projects on Github. Handsontable uses the COLSPAN/ROWSPAN for elements in the DOM so it should work well. You just need to remember to use `renderAllRows: true` and `viewportColumnRenderingOffset: instance.countCols()` to render all elements to the DOM.

Comment: thanks i fix this problems by your advice ,i remove the hidden elements in the table and use the  @linways/table-to-excel to export my excel success and the cells is merged ,thanks again